# Typesetting mixed-case acronyms with numbers

Tags: typography, acronyms

What are the various alternatives to typeset acronyms that contain lowercase letters, lowercase letters and numbers?

For example, take the acronym SOA4All.
The naive way would be to typeset it just like that:

```
SOA4All
```

This is not really nice, of couse.
A next step is to introduce small caps:

```
{\scshape soa}4{\scshape a}ll
```

Slightly better, but the number doesn't blend in all the well.
We could add old-style numerals:

```
{\scshape soa}\oldstylenums4{\scshape a}ll
```

This is kind-of OK, but the 4 is really low now, and the small `l`s still stick out.
Here they are all together:

[image]

Which alternatives do you see and what would you recommend?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I have edited your question to add the picture directly, as you can't do that yet.

Comment: How many such acronyms do you have? If it is just this one, I would go for the first form because the lowercase "l" has such an important height. Otherwise, I would probably suggest the variant with old-style numerals, as it is the more consistent one if you have many different acronyms (even though it may not look best with this particular one) – but it is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: In my view, the presence of lowercase letters precludes the use of smallcaps. Smallcaps are nice when you have an all-caps word, and I could accept them if it were "SOA4all". As for mixing smallcaps and numbers, if you can't get true "smallcaps" numbers, I'd prefer just resizing everything down.

Comment: @ienissei: The type of texts I write contains a lot of acronyms. So it's indeed a matter of consistency as well. For example, the acronym "SOA" would also occur, so if I go for small caps there, "SOA4All" should at least start with small caps.

Comment: @Jellby: How would you resize everything down?

Comment: With the `relsize` package: `\textsmaller{B3LYP}`

Comment: @RubenVerborgh SOA4All just won't typeset very well, so be consistent everywhere else and try to make SOA4All look as good as it can look while taking your other choices into consideration. It won't be perfect, but it sounds very possible to prevent it from standing out as ugly. How much freedom do you have with SOA4All? Can you do it entirely in small-caps? Can you write "all" entirely in lowercase roman?

Answer (score 5):

Whether or not you choose old-style numbers, my suggestion would be to add a bit of kerning around the 4 so as to make the acronym look a bit less crammed. Something smaller than a `\thinspace` (which is 3/18em):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\textsc{soa\kern.07em4\kern.07ema}ll

\textsc{soa\kern.07em\oldstylenums4\kern.07ema}ll

\end{document}
```

(Perhaps it could be even a bit less)

[image]

Comment: A bit of kerning helps indeed, it makes the acronym breathe a little.